# How to pass a prop from a Container to it's Component

Tags: reactjs, redux

So I've got a var i can pick up in my component although I can't be certain since there's nowhere i can put a console.log in the component but I think I have my var.

now how do I console.log it in my component?

this is in my constructor :

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        parameters: state.searchParameterStore.parameters,
        idUser: state.authenticate.idUser,
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        exportParameter: payload => dispatch(actions.setParameters(payload)),
        generateDoc: payload => dispatch(actions.generateDoc(payload)),
    };
}
```

And this is in my component :

```
const propTypes = {
    generateDoc: React.PropTypes.func,
    exportParameter: React.PropTypes.func,
    parameters: React.PropTypes.array,
    idUser: React.PropTypes.string,
};

class generateComponent extends Component {
generate() {
        const truc = this.props.idUser;
        console.log(truc);
}
}
SearchExtendedComponent.propTypes = propTypes;

export default SearchExtendedComponent;
```

and I get this in element inspector :

Undefined (on the line where the console log is)

Comment: Unfortunately you aren't going to get much help with the information you've given. Please post your code for us to see.

Comment: ok I added my code.

Comment: You probably mean `class SearchExtendedComponent extends Component { ...` instead of `class generateComponent extends Component {`.

Comment: OMG! yes! thank you! I didn't catch that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are apparently using react-redux and you need to connect your component:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchExtendedComponent);
```

This is the related example from the docs:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#inject-todos-and-all-action-creators-addtodo-completetodo--as-actions

Comment: yeah i did both those things.